# How to add and/or subtract a constant from some XML element values with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I have an XML file with lots of entries like the following:

```
<object>
    <name>buf</name>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>535</xmin>
        <ymin>725</ymin>
        <xmax>636</xmax>
        <ymax>821</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
```

Is there a way to use xmlstarlet (or another tool) to subtract the value of `10` from each `xmin` element's current value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To subtract the value of `10` from all `xmin` elements, use the following xmlstarlet command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//xmin" -x ".-10" input.xml
```

**Output of the sample XML is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ParentId>
  <object>
    <name>buf</name>
    <bndbox>
      <xmin>525</xmin>
      <ymin>725</ymin>
      <xmax>636</xmax>
      <ymax>821</ymax>
    </bndbox>
  </object>
</ParentId>
```